# TomEE freezes when invoking RESTful service operation multiple times (when security is applied)

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee

TomEE freezes when invoking RESTful service operation multiple times (when security is applied).

- TomEE works fine, when we have no security configuration. you can call one or more operations multiple times and it doesn't freeze.
- TomEE works a few times but freezes when operations are called multiple times in case security is configured against AD.

Can anyone tell me the causes and possible fixes?

When it freezes I get this error:

```
Jun 03, 2015 2:43:45 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve notifyStuckThreadDetected
WARNING: Thread "http-bio-8080-exec-8" (id=79) has been active for 66,464 milliseconds (since 6/3/15 2:42 PM) to serve the same request for http://localhost:8080/a_webservice/uri/ and may be stuck (configured threshold for this StuckThreadDetectionValve is 60 seconds). There is/are 1 thread(s) in total that are monitored by this Valve and may be stuck.
java.lang.Throwable
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:469)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getSearchReply(LdapClient.java:639)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.search(LdapClient.java:562)
```

Answer (score 1):

just takes a thread dump where it freezes, you'll see quickly why (identify the id of your process with jps and then run jstack )

Comment: I have added the error message in the question, how would I fix this.

Comment: it is linked to ldap which is not a tomee thing, the full stack would give more details but I guess it is in your ldap usage that you have to close properly connections

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is right my server.xml has ldap details. How do I close connections properly, is that an attribute in server.xml that I need to set?